# Splitting igraph in components and drawing components separately

Tags: r, igraph

I have a graph that has a total of 14 components of which 13 are isolated nodes and the major component has 128 nodes. Obviously, this large component is all cluttered and overlapped and I am just not able to make any sense out of it.

Can someone suggest how I draw only this large component as a separate graph so that I have a better resolution and meaningful interpretation? I am using R and igraph package

SHRINIVAS
INDIA

Answer (score 0):

You can use `decompse` like below (given graph object `g`)

```
sapply(decompose(g), plot)
```